# Can't map project-folders in vagrant/Code folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I am struggling with mapping in vagrant/code folder while configure homestead.when I do, it's shows `empty`.I spent hours on it but it,s not mapping.I am using OS X. I'll be thankful for your any help.
here is my`homestead.yaml` file I want to copy  my workspace folder to `vagrant/Code`

```
 --
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Workspace
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: cgc.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/CGC/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - cgc

variables:
   - key: APP_ENV
     value: local
```

Comment: Please give more information, what OS do you use, how did you install Homestead (all steps). If you think your settings are correct, try to run `vagrant provision` command.

Comment: I m using mac os. and I using vagrant provision.but still shows empty

Comment: Try to use `/Users/your_account_name/Workspace`, also is `Workspace` a right directory? I mean does it have Laravel project inside it? Does `vagrant up` work nd you're able to connect to the VM with `vagrant ssh`?

Comment: I tried this path..workspace is right directory containing laravel projects..vagrant up work and able to connect by vagrant ssh

Comment: Did you solve it?